# Procedure is checks if picturebox is empty and if it has tag. Not working properly

Tags: vb.net

I have 4 picture boxes on my form. I want my procedure to check if the picture does not contain a string tag, if it does not contain a string Tag, then place the picture on that box.  I run the procedure but nothing happens no error. It simply does not load my picture.  My best guess is that I have my IF condition wrong.  Here is my procedure:

```
    Private Sub btnAddImage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddImage.Click

    ofdBrowsePictures.Multiselect = False
    ofdBrowsePictures.Title = "Select Image to Upload"
    ofdBrowsePictures.Filter = "Image Files |*.jpg*"

    If ofdBrowsePictures.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        Dim PBs() As PictureBox = {picMainImage, picImage2, picImage3, picImage4}
        Dim nextPB = PBs.Where(Function(x) IsNothing(x.Image)).FirstOrDefault
        Dim nextTag = PBs.Where(Function(x) IsNothing(x.Tag)).FirstOrDefault

        If Not IsNothing(nextTag) Then

            nextPB.ImageLocation = ofdBrowsePictures.FileName


        End If


    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using "nextPB" which is checking for no image.  Your "nextTag" variable, however, is checking for no Tag.  Change it to:

```
Private Sub btnAddImage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddImage.Click
    ofdBrowsePictures.Multiselect = False
    ofdBrowsePictures.Title = "Select Image to Upload"
    ofdBrowsePictures.Filter = "Image Files |*.jpg*"

    If ofdBrowsePictures.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim PBs() As PictureBox = {picMainImage, picImage2, picImage3, picImage4}
        Dim nextTag = PBs.Where(Function(x) IsNothing(x.Tag)).FirstOrDefault
        If Not IsNothing(nextTag) Then
            nextTag.ImageLocation = ofdBrowsePictures.FileName
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Also, this isn't updating the Tag after placing an image in the PB, so not sure it will work as expected for the next click.  Don't forget to update the Tag value in nextTag if that's what you need the algorithm to do...